# subset strings without a pattern stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I want to extract elements of a character vector which do not match a given pattern. See the example:

```
x<-c("age_mean","n_aitd","n_sle","age_sd","n_poly","n_sero","child_age")
x_age<-str_subset(x,"age")
x_notage<-setdiff(x,x_age)
```

In this example I want to extract those strings which do not match the pattern "age". How to achieve this in a single call of str_subset ? What is the appropriate syntax of the pattern "not age". As you can see I am not very expert with regex. Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case there seems to be no reason to use `stringr` (efficiency perhaps). You may simply use `grep`:

```
grep("age", x, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "n_aitd" "n_sle"  "n_poly" "n_sero"
```

If, however, you want to stick with `str_stringr`, note that (from `?str_subset`)

> str_subset() is a wrapper around x[str_detect(x, pattern)], and is equivalent to grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE).

So,

```
x[!str_detect(x, "age")]
# [1] "n_aitd" "n_sle"  "n_poly" "n_sero"
```

or also

```
x[!grepl("age", x)]
# [1] "n_aitd" "n_sle"  "n_poly" "n_sero"
```